# How to access Vue component from standard JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I get access to a component's data via a window.addEventListener?
I want to hit the 'g' key and hide the Vue component test.

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
  Vue.component('test', {
    template: `<div id="box" v-if="visible"></div>`,
    data() {
      return {
        visible: true
      }
    }
  })
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  });
  window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key == 'g') {
      //set test.visible = false
    }
  });
  window.app = app;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <test></test>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the listener in the `created` component's [life cycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks). This will give you access to the instance, including the `visible` data property.

Make sure to also remove the listener once your component is destroyed.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  Vue.component('test', {
    template: `<div id="box" v-if="visible"></div>`,

    data() {
      return {
        visible: true
      }
    },

    created() {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', this.visibilityHandler)
    },

    destroyed() {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.visibilityHandler)
    },

    methods: {
      visibilityHandler(e) {
        if (e.key == 'g') {
          this.visible = false
        }
      }
    },
  });

  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
  });

  window.app = app;
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Ricky, worked beautifully. I'm starting to dig into these new JS frameworks.

Comment: De nada! Make sure to keep asking questions if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic inside of the component:

```
Vue.component('test', {
  template: `<div id="box" v-if="visible"></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      visible: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.key == 'g') {
        this.visible = false
      }
    });
  }
})
```